# Need to shift elements in deque. Code not working

Tags: c++, arrays, element, shift, deque

I want a function which shifts according to input index u. If u is negative, shift right, else left. Using the code below the resulting `deque` is the same as the input.

```
deque<float> move(deque<float>p, int u)
{
    if(u==0 || p.size()==1)
        return p;

    else if(u<0)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<abs(p.size()); i++)
        {
            int temp = p.back();
            p.pop_back();
            p.push_front(temp);
        }       
    }

    else
    {
        for(int i=0; i<p.size(); i++)
        {
            int temp = p.front();
            p.pop_front();
            p.push_back(temp);
        }
    }

    return p;
  }
```

Another variation to this code which seems to work fine in Python but not in C++ is this:

```
deque<float> move1(deque<float>p, int u)
{
    deque<float> q;

    for(int i=0; i<p.size(); i++)
        q.push_back(p[(i-u) % p.size()]);

     return q;
 }
```

Comment: I wouldn't call what you are doing "shifting" but "rotating". BTW: A fast way is to simply store the rotation offset and compute the resulting index dynamically. That way, you don't have to move elements at all. However, it makes inserting elements a bit complicated, because can't simply `push_front()` or `push_back()`. BTW2: What's the issue with the second algorithm?

Comment: Let me update the second algorithm to show you exactly what I want to do now.

Comment: Furthermore, I want a function which shifts each element forward and add some bit of it's neighbour to the new value.
Another variation to this code which seems to work fine in Python but not in C++ is this. Please feel free to comment any queries, as I think I haven't been able to convey the question correctly:

Comment: int pExact = 0.8;
    int pOvershoot = 0.2;
    int pUndershoot = 0.1;

    deque<float> move2(deque<float> p, int u)
    {
        deque<float> q;
        for (int i=0; i<p.size(); i++)
        {
            float s = pExact * p[(i-u) % p.size()];
            s = s + pOvershoot * p[(i-u-1) % p.size()];
            s = s + pUndershoot * p[(i-u+1) % p.size()];
            q.push_back(s);
        }
        return q;
    }

Comment: Sorry I am new to stackoverflow. They are not allowing me to do anything due to abuses on network.

Comment: @Sami Kohmonen see the code above

Comment: If you want to do something new, please post a new question. For this question though, I still don't see anything incorrect in the `move2()` function that you posted. What exactly does it do different than what you expected?

Comment: it seems to work for values of 1 or -1. But not for greater. For example 2

Comment: Found my issue, Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually shifting it one step to left or right, you are shifting it left or right as many times as there are items. This, of course, will result in the same order as it was.

Remove the loops to get what you want to achieve

```
deque<float> move(deque<float>p, int u)
{
    if(u==0 || p.size()==1)
        return p;

    else if(u<0)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<-u; i++)
        {
            int temp = p.back();
            p.pop_back();
            p.push_front(temp);
        }
    }

    else
    {
        for(int i=0; i<u; i++)
        {
            int temp = p.front();
            p.pop_front();
            p.push_back(temp);
        }
    }

    return p;
}
```

The second code should work just fine as it is written. It accesses elements displaced by `u` steps and stores them in another deque, returning it. What is not working with it?

Comment: Yes exactly, I want to shift it as many times as the index u. Meaning,
u = 2        shift left two times
u =-2        shift right two times

Comment: @MohsinAnees Oh, then loop until u, not p.size(). Edited answer

Comment: Can anyone comment on the second peice of code given in the question.

Comment: @MohsinAnees I did. I see nothing wrong with it. What doesn't work?

Comment: I cant imagine how first else if loops.

Answer (score 6):

Your code could be much simpler if you used [std::rotate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) from the standard library. For example:

```
std::deque<float> move(std::deque<float> p, int u)
{
    if (u == 0 || p.empty()) {
        return p;
    }
    if (u < 0) {
        std::rotate(p.begin(), std::prev(p.end(), -u), p.end());
    } else {
        std::rotate(p.begin(), std::next(p.begin(), u), p.end());
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: I like this. Once writing this, I figure out, that move is not needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, `(i-u) % p.size()` will be negative if `u` is bigger than `i`, as the `%` operator does not change sign.

You could use `(i - u + p.size()) % p.size()` instead.